# (Spring, Thymeleaf) How to request to controller 'POST' with list of model inside a model?

Tags: html, spring, post, spring-boot, thymeleaf

### Issue

I tried below sources. but occurred an error 'Validation failed for object'.
Referenced by this link(http://bitbybitblog.com/forms-and-data-models-in-spring-mvc/).
I guess how to form data(input values) send to the controller for the model 'Shop' without any error.
I think unmatched model 'Shop' and HTML form data. cannot figure out the solution.
*How to fix 'tag' input name?*

### Sources

```
public class Tag {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Date regDate = new Date();
}
```

```
public class Shop {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String url;
    private String featureImagePath;
    private List<Tag> tag = new ArrayList<>();
    private ShopStatus status = ShopStatus.SHOW;
    private Date expireDate;
    private Date updateDate;
    private Date regDate;
}
```

```
Controller

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute Shop shop) {
    if (shop.getId() == null) {
        shopService.createShop(shop);
    }

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

```
HTML/Thymeleaf

<form name="editor" method="post" action="/edit/update">
<fieldset>
    <input name='name' th:value='${data.name}'/>
    <input name='tag[0].id'/><input name='tag[0].name'/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

### Result

occurred this problem then submit the form 'editor' on the browser.

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Validation failed for object='shop'. Error count: 1

Comment: That blog post about jsp spring but you have tried thymeleaf instead of jsp. You need to check thymleaf documentation. I can see few things are missing here. Form doesn't have th:object and form objects attributes need to be binded using th:field. Documentation is here http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form

Comment: @SAP thanks your reply. please refer to this thymeleaf version is 3.x. I already tried added "th:object" attribute several times and checked document.
didn't occurred the other pages without 'th:object'.

Comment: You are not following Thymeleaf documentation. Check this: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form. you haven't included any attributes like 'th:field' in your input field which used to map your fields with ModelAttribute in controller

Comment: @Afridi I see. but it's not sure. I found the exact problems. thanks your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My source has no problem. occurred another side.
Actually HTML side has 'expireDate' input. but sent to the controller ***NULL value*** of the input (model 'Shop' didn't define a default value).
It's my mistake.

in the addition, we can use **"FORM"** without 'th:object' if follow below the controller source.

---

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String edit(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("data", new Shop());
    return "shop/edit";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute Shop shop) {
    if (shop.getId() == null) {
        shopService.createShop(shop);
    }

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: Of course you can use without th:object if you put new Shop() object to the Model. However, you haven't added a tag(s) to the tag array list.